# Asp.net Identity 3 return 403 Unauthorized request instead of redirect for WebAPI call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-3

I used Asp.net Identity 3 within Asp.net core project (only compile against net451.)

Here is the question, when I call the WebAPI with [Authorize] tag, the system always return the login url instead of 401 for unauthorized call. I wonder how to make it return 401 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are redirected because `ApplicationCookie` sets `AutomaticChallenge` to `true` by default.

To prevent redirection use:

```
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
```

Comment: Previous solution is anyway a good hack if you want to handle both 401 and 403 HTTP responses. Because using AutomaticChallenge you'll always get a 401 AFAICT.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out in startup.cs

`services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()`

change to the following code will take care this issue.

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            })
```

Answer (score 3):

maxisam's answer was helpful, but things changed again. There is no `Cookies` property on `IdentityOptions` anymore. However, this works:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```